# How to display only layers where is my selection in clipper?

Tags: qgis

I'm using the Raster->clipper plugin to clip raster layers but I've a lot of layer and every time I have to search the right one in the big list in the input raster file. I would like to see the list of only the layers contained in the selection and not the list of all the rasters layers of the project.